# About sparkSql optimization - left join between small and large table

Tags: apache-spark-sql

```
spark-sql --master yarn --driver-memory 10G --executor-memory 20G --executor-cores 20 --num-executors 20
```

(I applied for the resource above.Forgive me for not applying for resources on a proportional basis...)

sql as follow:

```
select 'ADDRESS',count(a.pid)
FROM (SELECT pa.pid
       FROM dmgr.ex_p10ids_address pa
      WHERE pa.pt IN ('20200227')
        AND pa.src_sys = 'APP0001'
        AND pa.endtime = '99991231999'
        AND pa.idtype NOT IN ('00')
        AND certificate_type(pa.idtype, 'P10IDS') <> '0') a
LEFT JOIN (SELECT pr.apid, pr.pid
           FROM p10ids_riskcon pr
          WHERE pr.classcode NOT IN
                ('26371100', '26371200', '26371300', '13770100', '26376000')) b
ON a.pid = b.apid
OR a.pid = b.pid;
```

--takes 6hrs,33mins,15sec.

two src tables have different order of magnitudes:

```
select count(1) from (SELECT count(pa.pid)
       FROM dmgr.ex_p10ids_address pa
      WHERE pa.pt IN ('20200227')
        AND pa.src_sys = 'APP0001'
        AND pa.endtime = '99991231999'
        AND pa.idtype NOT IN ('00')
        AND certificate_type(pa.idtype, 'P10IDS') <> '0' --group by pa.pid
        ) t; --46644 /group by:45094

select count(1) from(
SELECT pr.apid, pr.pid
           FROM p10ids_riskcon pr
          WHERE pr.classcode NOT IN
                ('26371100', '26371200', '26371300', '13770100', '26376000')
              --group by pr.apid, pr.pid
) t ; --14,9386,2737 / group by:4,8973,0113
```

How to reduce running time? What's wrong with my spark-sql resource?
Hope Your Comments~

Comment: This is not relevant to performance, but your first 2 queries will not return the same results.  In your second query, you have `AND b.classcode NOT IN...`.  That will result in an inner join to `p10ids_riskcon`.  You need to move that to your ON clause.

Comment: @Andrew:I move the conditonal statement to ON clause as: `LEFT JOIN p10ids_riskcon b
   ON (a.pid = b.apid OR a.pid = b.pid)  AND b.classcode NOT IN ('26371100', '26371200', '26371300', '13770100', '26376000');`And the execution time is as long as the first sql.

Comment: And the second sql is used actually. I just want to optimize it...